# python Win service with multiprocessing error

Tags: python, windows-services, multiprocessing

I created by py2exe exe program which uses multiprocessing and it work fine! But when I am trying to create windows service with win32serviceutil, win32service get error - can't pickle  it's not found as builtin_PYHANDLE.

Here is my code:

```
 import win32serviceutil
 import win32service
 import win32event
 import servicemanager
 from multiprocessing import Process 
 import time
 import datetime

 class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
_svc_name_ = "Siemens Service Reader"
_svc_display_name_ = "Siemens Service Reader"
_svc_description_ = "__read data from siemens controller 169.254.0.201" 
def __init__(self,args):
    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
    self.hWaitResume = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
    self.timeout = 2000  
    self.resumeTimeout = 2000
    self._paused = False

 ... description of service
 ... service functions     
def SvcDoRun(self):
    servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                          servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                          (self._svc_name_,''))
    self.main()  

def connect_controller(self):
    pass

def connect_controller2(self):
    pass

def main(self):
    servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Starting Siemens reader service...")
    while True:
        p = Process(target= self.connect_controller)
        p.start()

        p2 = Process(target=self.connect_controller)
        p2.start()

        p.join()
        p2.join()
        rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
        if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Siemens reading is stopping")
        if self._paused:
            servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Siemens reading is on pause")              
        while self._paused:
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitResume, self.resumeTimeout)
            if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                self._paused = False
                servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Yeah! Let's continue!")
                break                  

if __name__ == '__main__':
     win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Can anyone help with this?
How to pickle function object?

Answer (score 0):

If this is not just a copy paste mistake, you are (probably) missing a `"` at the end of the _svc_description_